# Possible to display an Array with for loop and InnerHTML?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, for-loop

I just wanted to display my Array inside of either an div or a heading.

The code i posted down below only displays the last part of the "List".

When i tried to use:  document.write instead, everything worked fine.

Is there any special trick to display the list the same way document.write does using my Code below?

```
var Users = ["Till", "Didi", "Klausi", "Heinz"];
for (var i = 0; i < Users.length; i++) {
    document.querySelector("div").innerHTML = Users[i] + " is always on my page " + "<br>";
}
```

Comment: You're overwriting your div with every name. Try debug it you'll see

Comment: So is there no other way to use loops and innerHTML or InnerText ?

Comment: sure check out the answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Build the whole HTML first by iterating on the array and concatenating strings. And then set it as `innerHTML` of the `div`.

```js
var Users = ["Till", "Didi", "Klausi", "Heinz"];

var _html = "";
for (var i = 0; i < Users.length; i++) {
    _html += Users[i] + " is always on my page " + "<br>";
}

document.querySelector("div").innerHTML = _html;
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Every time the loop runs it inserts the current iterable item into the HTML, replacing the one previous. So add a variable outside of the loop and append to it using `var x += User[i]`.

Answer (score 0):

```
var separator = ' is always on my page<br>';
var html = Users.join(separator) + separator;
document.querySelector("div").innerHTML = html;
// writes
// "Till is always on my page<br>Didi is always on my page<br>Klausi is always on my page<br>Heinz is always on my page<br>"
```